# How would I make an object visible once a checkbox has been checked?

Tags: c#, checkbox, visible

Im wondering how I would reveal a label, and a textbox once a checkbox has been checked.

I know in my project, everything below initialize component starts once the form is visible, so i try this.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        label9.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        label9.Visible = false;
        textBox4.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

but that doesnt work, and so i put it in a while(true) loop, which is just an infinite loop

```
public Form2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            label9.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label9.Visible = false;
            textBox4.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

but that doesnt work either, if someone knows the answer, please let me know :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the checked changed event of the checkbox.

And call it from the constructor to initialize the state of the controls.

Also you only need to assign the `Checked` property to the `Visible` properties.

```
public Form2()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  checkBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label9.Visible = checkBox1.Checked;
  textBox4.Visible = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

Or you can use the form load to leave the constructor as is:

```
public Form2()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  checkBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

[Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms)

[Control.Created Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.created)

But never put an infinite loop in the constructor or in form load or shown!

And never put such infinite loop without break somewhere...

That will freeze the application in it.